# Is Kinect SDK 2 compatible with Xbox 360 Kinect?

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I am trying to develop a face recognition app for fun using Kinect for Xbox 360. I would like to figure out which SDK and version of Visual Studio should I use for best access to the Kinect.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Is Kinect SDK 2 compatible with Xbox 360 Kinect?

**No**, the Kinect SDK 2.0 is not compatible with any Kinect v1 sensor. From [DreamSpark.com](https://www.dreamspark.com/rss/news.aspx?ID=35&FeedType=productfeed):

> Kinect for Windows SDK 2.0 [...] requires the new Kinect for Windows v2 sensor, or an Xbox One Kinect with the Kinect Adapter for Windows. SDK 2.0 is not compatible with the original Kinect for Windows sensor.

If you need to develop with Kinect for Xbox 360, you should use [Microsoft Kinect SDK 1.8](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40278).

Comment: I just connected an Xbox 360 Kinect to my Windows 10 PC.  I found that I needed to install SDK 1.8 in Windows 7 compatibility mode.  Also, I found that the USB adapter gave me a Device Descriptor Request Failed warning, but it still worked.

Comment: hi there, even the SDK 1.8 is for the Kinect for Windows, not for the XBOX 360(see it in your link). I am confused. I assume that Kinect for Windows and Kinect for XOBX 360 is different, correct?

Comment: Also the link you provided in DreamSpark.com has gone. I did found SDK v2 and it's said for Kinect v2 sensor which confused me, as I only know Kinect for Windows or Kinect for XBOX 360/XBOX One. So have you tried the SDK v2 for Kinect for XOBX 360??

Comment: Kinect for Xbox360 and Kinect for Windows (both also known as Kinect v1) were two slightly different version of the same device. They looked pretty much the same, except for what were written in the cases: ["Xbox360" for the first](https://www.gamesmen.com.au/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/i/m/img2-33292.jpg), ["Kinect" for the second](https://o.aolcdn.com/images/dims?quality=85&image_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.blogcdn.com%2Fwww.engadget.com%2Fmedia%2F2012%2F05%2Fk4w-sensorangle.jpg&client=amp-blogside-v2&signature=8ec2d0afc7267dea9878429f3e1f1e6bee09ecd1)

Comment: In addition, Kinect for Xbox One is also known as Kinect v2, and it works with SDK 2.0. You can only use SDK 1.x with Kinect for Xbox360 or Kinect for Windows, while SDK 2.0 only works with Kinect for Xbox One

Comment: hi @VitoGentile so if they were same device, would the SDK 1.8 be applicable to both of them? Also, I have a feeling that the SDK 2 could be applicable to the Kinect for XBOX 360. Could you please confirm it? thanks

Comment: As I said, Kinect SDK v1.x only works with Kinect v1 (i.e. Kinect for Xbox 360 and Kinect for Windows), while Kinect SDK 2.0 is only usable with Kinect v2 (i.e. Kinect for Xbox One, [this one](https://timedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2014/04/kinect-xbox-one.jpg))

Comment: Also note that Kinect for Windows **v2** has been completely replaced by Kinect for Xbox One + a Kinect Adapter. So basically Kinect for Windows v2 IS EQUAL to Kinect for Xbox One

Comment: thanks @VitoGentile the last one, I found Kinect SDK 1.8 and Kinect for Windows Developer Toolkit on the same page. Just wonder what are the differences between them? My feeling is Toolkit = SDK + sample codes ?