# Which version of Xbox is compatible with Kinect SDK 2.0

Tags: sensors

i wanted to know which version of Xbox is compatible with [Kinect SDK 2.0](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/kinect/).

I was going to run Kinect v2 application on my system; which Kinect sensor should i purchase? I am new in this kind of stuff, and I have no idea where to being and how it will work for me,

So please tell me which sensor should I buy for Kinect v2 for Windows

- Xbox one?
- Xbox 360?

Looking forward for your quick responses. Thanks!

Comment: Xbox one = v2.0 See here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217577/is-kinect-sdk-2-compatible-with-xbox-360-kinect